# A word for the pout made when thinking

Tags: vocabulary

How would you call the pout that one makes when assessing a situation? Is there a word or phrase to designate this kind of grimace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would just call that a [frown](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/frown) (note that it can indicate *concentration* as well as negative emotions like disapproval or displeasure):

> NOUN
>
> A facial expression indicating disapproval, displeasure, or concentration, typically with the corners of the mouth turned down.
>
> > ‘she leans back uneasily, her mouth forming a pensive frown’
> >
> > ‘a frown of disapproval’